Nodes and related lines are not aligned with each other in NetwokX
I tried to create a proper visualization of my topology, but the nodes and the connecting lines are not aligned. Could you please advise me on how to fix this?
Here are the code:
positions = {}
labels = {}
sizes = []
colors = []

for node in Topology.first().nodes():
    positions[node] = node.coordinates
    labels[node] = node.id
    sizes.append(500)
    if len(node.base_station.edge_servers) > 0:
        colors.append("red")
    else:
        colors.append("black")

def rescale_positions(positions, scale_x=1, scale_y=1):
    rescaled_positions = {}
    for node, (x, y) in positions.items():
        rescaled_positions[node] = (x * scale_x, y * scale_y)
    return rescaled_positions

positions_rescaled = rescale_positions(positions, scale_x=100, scale_y=100)

# Draw the graph with adjusted settings
nx.draw_networkx(
    Topology.first(),
    pos=positions_rescaled,
    node_color=colors,
    node_size=sizes,
    labels=labels,
    font_size=10,
    font_weight="bold",
    font_color="whitesmoke"
)

The output plot is as below:


That's interesting. You did not share the Topology object data, so I reconstructed the graph:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.empty_graph(range(25))

G.add_edges_from(
    [(node, node+1) for node in range(24) if (node+1) % 5] +
    [(node, node+5) for node in range(20)] +
    [(node, node+4) for node in range(20) if node % 5 and not node // 5 % 2] +
    [(node-1, node+5) for node in range(20) if node % 5 and node // 5 % 2]
)

pos = {node: (node % 5 + node // 5 % 2 / 2, node // 5)
       for node in G.nodes()}

labels = {node: node+1 for node in G.nodes()}

node_color = ["red" if node+1 in (3, 5, 8, 9, 18, 19, 22) else "black"
              for node in G.nodes()]

nx.draw_networkx(G,
                 pos=pos,
                 labels=labels,
                 node_color=node_color,
                 node_size=500,
                 font_size=10,
                 font_color="whitesmoke",
                 font_weight="bold",
                 with_labels=True)


As we see, the edges are correctly plotted, at least when the graph object is defined by hand.
Note also that re-scaling node positions has no effect, as their relative positions remain the same:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rescale_positions(positions, scale_x=1, scale_y=1):
    rescaled_positions = {}
    for node, (x, y) in positions.items():
        rescaled_positions[node] = (x * scale_x, y * scale_y)
    return rescaled_positions

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(6, 3), constrained_layout=True)

for i, scale in enumerate([1, 100]):
    ax[i].set_title(f"scale={scale}")
    
    nx.draw_networkx(G,
                     ax=ax[i],
                     pos=rescale_positions(pos, scale, scale),
                     labels=labels,
                     node_color=node_color,
                     node_size=300,
                     font_size=9,
                     font_color="whitesmoke",
                     font_weight="bold",
                     with_labels=True)


So I can't seem to reproduce your issue on networkx==3.3.
